# Cupertino Tab Bar

Tags: flutter, tabbar, flutter-cupertino

I am trying to implement the Cupertino bottom tab bar. I have 2 issues. When I call the widgetBuilder in the Cupertino tab view I get 'The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null'', so add a null check '!' but then it requires another one.

Then, when I try to return the CupertinoHomeScaffold with currentTab, onSelectTab, widgetBuilder as field it says parameter 'key' is required. Not sure what I should do.

Let me know if you see anything! Thanks in advance..!

```
        import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        
        enum TabItem { jobs, entries, account }
        
        class TabItemData {
          const TabItemData({required this.title, required this.icon});
        
          final String title;
          final IconData icon;
        
          static const Map<TabItem, TabItemData> allTabs = {
            TabItem.jobs: TabItemData(title: 'Jobs', icon: Icons.work),
            TabItem.entries: TabItemData(title: 'entries', icon: Icons.view_headline),
            TabItem.account: TabItemData(title: 'entries', icon: Icons.person),
          };
        }
        
        class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
          @override
          _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
        }
        
        class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
          TabItem _currentTab = TabItem.jobs;
        
          Map<TabItem, WidgetBuilder> get widgetBuilder {
            return {
              TabItem.jobs: (_) => Container(),
              TabItem.entries: (_) => Container(),
              TabItem.account: (_) => Container(),
            };
          }
        
          void _select(TabItem tabItem) {
            setState(() => _currentTab = tabItem);
          }
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return CupertinoHomeScaffold(
              currentTab: _currentTab,
              onSelectTab: _select,
              widgetBuilder: widgetBuilder,
            );
          }
        }
        
        class CupertinoHomeScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
          const CupertinoHomeScaffold({
            required Key key,
            required this.currentTab,
            required this.onSelectTab,
            required this.widgetBuilder,
          }) : super(key: key);
        
          final TabItem currentTab;
          final ValueChanged<TabItem> onSelectTab;
          final Map<TabItem, WidgetBuilder> widgetBuilder;
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return CupertinoTabScaffold(
              tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
                items: [
                  _buildItem(TabItem.jobs),
                  _buildItem(TabItem.entries),
                  _buildItem(TabItem.account),
                ],
                onTap: (index) => onSelectTab(TabItem.values[index]),
              ),
              tabBuilder: (context, index) {
                final item = TabItem.values[index];
                return CupertinoTabView(
                  builder: (context) => widgetBuilder![item](context),
                );
              },
            );
          }
        
          BottomNavigationBarItem _buildItem(TabItem tabItem) {
            final itemData = TabItemData.allTabs[tabItem];
            return BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(itemData!.icon),
              label: itemData.title,
            );
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `key` a nullable variable:

```dart
Key? key,
```

For `widgetBuilder`, you need to put `!` after `]`:

```dart
widgetBuilder[item]!(context),
```

**Working Example**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );

enum TabItem { jobs, entries, account }

class TabItemData {
  const TabItemData({required this.title, required this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;

  static const Map<TabItem, TabItemData> allTabs = {
    TabItem.jobs: TabItemData(title: 'Jobs', icon: Icons.work),
    TabItem.entries: TabItemData(title: 'entries', icon: Icons.view_headline),
    TabItem.account: TabItemData(title: 'entries', icon: Icons.person),
  };
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  TabItem _currentTab = TabItem.jobs;

  Map<TabItem, WidgetBuilder> get widgetBuilder {
    return {
      TabItem.jobs: (_) => Container(),
      TabItem.entries: (_) => Container(),
      TabItem.account: (_) => Container(),
    };
  }

  void _select(TabItem tabItem) {
    setState(() => _currentTab = tabItem);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoHomeScaffold(
      currentTab: _currentTab,
      onSelectTab: _select,
      widgetBuilder: widgetBuilder,
    );
  }
}

class CupertinoHomeScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  const CupertinoHomeScaffold({
    Key? key,
    required this.currentTab,
    required this.onSelectTab,
    required this.widgetBuilder,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final TabItem currentTab;
  final ValueChanged<TabItem> onSelectTab;
  final Map<TabItem, WidgetBuilder> widgetBuilder;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: [
          _buildItem(TabItem.jobs),
          _buildItem(TabItem.entries),
          _buildItem(TabItem.account),
        ],
        onTap: (index) => onSelectTab(TabItem.values[index]),
      ),
      tabBuilder: (context, index) {
        final item = TabItem.values[index];
        return CupertinoTabView(
          builder: (context) => widgetBuilder[item]!(context),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  BottomNavigationBarItem _buildItem(TabItem tabItem) {
    final itemData = TabItemData.allTabs[tabItem];
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(itemData!.icon),
      label: itemData.title,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. If you think this answer solves your question, could you mark this answer as accepted?

Comment: Hey! I have tried to +1 but can't as I do not have enough points(I am new). I have another (small) question. with this structure, when I am on the first page, when I pop the context I am getting an error message, so you know another way to pop back to logging screen without going back to the Cupertino?

Comment: Upvoting is different. You could accept the answer by clicking on 'check mark'.

Comment: Could you give an example of the new issue? I didn't understand the pop issue.

Comment: So basically, in the HomePage class, Cupertino is implemented with a _currentTab = TabItem.jobs, where the route goes to the First_page. But I have created a log_out functionality on this first page, which pop the context. So when I try to log out and pop back, I go to a red screen on my first page, but the other tab of the CupertinoScaffold looks fine.

Comment: HomePage is the only route on the Navigation Stack. You can't pop from there.

Comment: No, so I try to pop from the FirstPage(), which is set as TabItem.jobs: (_) => FirstPage(). but when I try to pop, I do not pop from the Cupertino view and get a red page for this specific page.

Comment: to get to the first page I came from the register page.

Comment: `TabItem.jobs: (_) => FirstPage()` is not a Route.